# GCC not performing loop invariant code motion

Tags: c++, gcc, optimization, g++, loop-invariant

I decided to check the result of loop invariant code motion optimization using g++. However, when I compiled the following code with `-fmove-loop-invariants` and analysed its assembly, I saw that `k + 17` calculation is still performed in the loop body.

What could prevent the compiler from optimizing it?

May be the compiler concludes that it is more efficient to recalculate `k + 17`?

```
int main()
{
    int k = 0;
    std::cin >> k;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i)
    {
        int n = k + 17; // not moved out of the loop
        printf("%d\n", n);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Tried `g++ -O0 -fmove-loop-invariants`, `g++ -O3` and `g++ -O3 -fmove-loop-invariants` using both g++ 4.6.3 and g++ 4.8.3.

Comment: For all the compiler knows, calling operator>> on k stored a pointer to k in a global variable (k "escapes"), and calling printf might modify k using that global pointer. The compiler is thus unable to perform the optimization you would like. If instead you write a function that takes k as argument by value, the computation of k+17 is moved before the loop.

Comment: @MarcGlisse Thanks, got it. I removed `int k = 0; std::cin >> k;` and made `k` a parameter: `main(int k, char **argv)`. Invariant is moved starting from `-O1`. The last small question is why invariant is not moved when compiling with `-O0 -fmove-loop-invariants`?

Comment: gcc 5.x doesn't seem to move the calculation ... at -O1 and higher it uses `lea     esi, [rax+17]` within the loop, perhaps as you say this doesn't take any more cycles than just loading rax by itself.  clang 3.7 still does `add esi, 17` within the loop even at `-O3`

Comment: `-O0 -fmove-loop-invariants` does not make sense, as -O0 disables all optimizations (even if you try to enable them with -f flags).

Comment: @MarcGlisse Ah, I see. Missed it in the docs: "Most optimizations are only enabled if an -O level is set on the command line. Otherwise they are disabled, even if individual optimization flags are specified." I wish gcc notified me about suppressing options. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**: Ignore my previous answer. You can see that the calculation has been folded into a constant. Therefore it ***is*** performing the loop invariant optimization.

---

Because of the [as-if rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15718262/what-exactly-is-the-as-if-rule). Simply put, the compiler is not allowed to make any optimizations that may affect the *observable behavior* of the program, in this case the `printf`. You can see what happens if you make `n` volatile and remove the `printf`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i)
{
    volatile int n = k + 17; // not moved out of the loop
}

// Example assembly output for GCC 4.6.4
// ...
        movl    $10000, %eax
        addl    $17, %edx
.L2:
        subl    $1, %eax
        movl    %edx, 12(%rsp)
// ...
```

Comment: How can precalucaltion of `k+17` influence _observable behaviour_ of `printf`? And unfortunately, I do not understand your demonstration of _as-if rule_ regarding my question. In your example when you declare a variable `volatile`, you tell the compiler not to throw away `n` (i.e. you tell here that optimizing `n` can actually influence _observable behaviour_), but it does not influence `k+17` precalculation and it actually does loop invariant optimization (as you pointed out in your edit).